# StackOverFlowException was Unhandled on For Loop

Tags: vb.net, exception, stack-overflow

I just made my  Card Selection Dynamic, instead of a sequence of 5 if/elseif statements.

```
Private Sub PlayElse()
    Dim StartHeads As Integer
    Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5, CardCheckBox6, CardCheckBox7, CardCheckBox8, CardCheckBox9, _
                                          CardCheckBox10, CardCheckBox11, CardCheckBox12, CardCheckBox13, CardCheckBox14, CardCheckBox15, CardCheckBox16, CardCheckBox17, _
                                          CardCheckBox18, CardCheckBox19, CardCheckBox20, CardCheckBox21, CardCheckBox22, CardCheckBox23, CardCheckBox24, CardCheckBox25}
    'Reset Number Generator
    Number = (DeckGroup(Rnd.Next(0, DeckGroup.Count)).ID)

    'card 1-5
    For StartHeads = 0 To 4
        If CardCheckBoxArray(StartHeads).Checked = True And DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
            'Grab New Card From Deck
            DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
            Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
            CardTypeArray(StartHeads) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
            CardCheckBoxArray(StartHeads).Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
            NumberArray(StartHeads) = Number
        Else
            Call PlayElse()
        End If
```

This was my original code (note there is an End If. I just didn't want to repeat the code through cards 2-5)

```
If CardCheckBox1.Checked = True And DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
    'Grab New Card From Deck
    DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
    Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
    CardTypeArray(0) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
    CardCheckBox1.Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
    NumberArray(0) = Number
```

Nothing has really changed except, any spot with a 0 is no represented by the corresponding number in the loop. I have several loops similar to this one in my project, yet somehow this is the one that gets a stackoverflow exception. The CardCheckBoxes in the CardCheckBoxArray goes up to 25 because there are 5 players in the game. Any CardCheckBox past 6 in this particular statement simply isn't accessed, since this logic only represents player 1's cards.
(Forgot to mention the continue buttons leads to the top of the sub-procedure when the error occurs, highlighting `Private Sub Playelse()`.)

Comment: before, did you also have `Call PlayElse()` inside `Else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause for stack overflow exceptions, as is the case here, is when you have a recursive method which calls itself too many times.  Each time a method calls itself, it adds more data to the stack.  The data isn't removed from the stack until the method exits.  For instance, the following method is guaranteed to throw a `StackOverFlowException`:

```
Public Sub Fail(count As Integer)
    Fail(count + 1)
End Sub
```

As you can see, when the `Fail` method, in my example is called, it infinitely calls itself over and over again, never exiting.  Therefore, the data on the stack keeps growing until eventually it runs out of space and throws the exception.

Comment: Nothing is being accumulated though until the procedure finds a matching DeckGroup().QuantityInteger > 0. I understand your sub, but all that is happening during failed execution is the declaration of the startheads integer, cardcheck array, generation of a new random number, then it checks if cards 1-5 in the players hand are not already filled. At least that is the way I understand it. Is there a way to generate the same results without the overflow then, while retaining the dynamic characteristic of the code?

Answer (score 0):

`Sub PlayElse` calls itself recursively in the `Else` case. You always must insure that recursions terminate at some point, otherwise you end up in an infinite recursion that throws a stack overflow exception.

The `If` condition says `... And DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger > 0`. If this is the case `DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger` is decremented. At some point it will be zero and the `Else` case will be executed, calling `PlayElse` which will again execute the `Else` case because `QuantityInteger` is zero now, and so on.

Should `Call PlayElse()` be at the end of the `Then` case instead?

Comment: The random number generator generates a "new" random number every time the sub procedure is rebooted. Eventually it runs into an item in deckgroup().quantity that is > 0 then ends successfully. That is how it grabs the specialty card from the deck, and places it into the players hand.

Comment: This means that the quantity of a random DeckGroup will be decremented, but if all the quantities are `0` you still get an infinite recursion. Step through the method in the debugger and you will see what happens.